Why does NDSolve fail to converge when solving for Sadowsky ribbon with nonzero θ?
I am working with the control equations of a Sadowsky ribbon, where the basic equations eqs and boundary conditions bc0 and bc1 are derived from the Kirchhoff rod theory, and have been validated. These equations are relatively straightforward, but the Sadowsky ribbon has a nonlinear constitutive relation, which is given in the eqsadd set, and the corresponding boundary conditions given in the bc0add set.
\[Theta] = 0; init = {9, 0, 0, 0, 0, -50, 9, 0}; 
eqs = {x'[s] == d3x[s], y'[s] == d3y[s], z'[s] == d3z[s], n1'[s] == n2[s]*k3[s], n2'[s] == n3[s]*k1[s] - n1[s]*k3[s], n3'[s] == -n2[s]*k1[s], d3x'[s] == -k1[s]*d2x[s], d3y'[s] == -k1[s]*d2y[s], d3z'[s] == -k1[s]*d2z[s], M1'[s] == M2[s]*k3[s] + n2[s], M2'[s] == M3[s]*k1[s] - M1[s]*k3[s] - n1[s], M3'[s] == -M2[s]*k1[s],d1x'[s] == k3[s]*d2x[s], d2x'[s] == k1[s]*d3x[s] - k3[s]*d1x[s], d1y'[s] == k3[s]*d2y[s], d2y'[s] == k1[s]*d3y[s] - k3[s]*d1y[s], d1z'[s] == k3[s]*d2z[s], d2z'[s] == k1[s]*d3z[s] - k3[s]*d1z[s]}; 
bc0 = {x[0] == 0, y[0] == 0, z[0] == 0, d1x[0] == 0, d1y[0] == 0, d1z[0] == 1, d2x[0] == 0, d2y[0] == -1, d2z[0] == 0, d3x[0] == 1, d3y[0] == 0, d3z[0] == 0}; 
bc1 = {x[1] == 0.5, y[1] == 0, z[1] == 0, Cos[\[Theta]]  d1y[1] + d1z[1]  Sin[\[Theta]] == 0, d2x[1] == 0, Cos[\[Theta]]  d3z[1] - d3y[1]  Sin[\[Theta]] == 0}; 
var = {x, y, z, d1x, d1y, d1z, d2x, d2y, d2z, d3x, d3y, d3z, M1, M2, M3, n1, n2, n3, k1, k3}; 
eqsadd = {k1'[s] == (k1[s]^4  (M2[s]  k3[s]  (k1[s]^2 + k3[s]^2) + n2[s]  (k1[s]^2 + 3  k3[s]^2)))/(((k1[s]^2 + k3[s]^2)^3)), k3'[s] == (k1[s]^3  (4 n2[s]  k3[s]^3 + M2[s]  (-k1[s]^4 + k3[s]^4)))/((2  (k1[s]^2 + k3[s]^2)^3))}; 
bc0add = {M1[0]*k1[0]^3 == k1[0]^4 - k3[0]^4, M3[0]*k1[0]^2 == 2 (k1[0]^2 +k3[0]^2)*k3[0]}; 
sol = NDSolve[Join[eqs, bc0, bc1, eqsadd, bc0add], var, {s, 0, 1}, Method -> {"Shooting", "StartingInitialConditions" -> {M1[0] == init[[1]], M2[0] == init[[2]], M3[0] == init[[3]], n1[0] == init[[4]], n2[0] == init[[5]], n3[0] == init[[6]], k1[0] == init[[7]], k3[0] == init[[8]]}, MaxIterations -> 10000}]

I have also supplied the init set, which serves as the initial guess when applying the shooting method. The results appear quite good. However, the issue arises when I attempt to solve the system with θ ≠ 0 (where θ represents an angle parameter). Even if θ is small, Mathematica fails to achieve a convergent solution. I have experimented with multiple solvers, but the problem still persists.
Is there a specific reason why Mathematica has difficulty converging in this situation? Are there any techniques or strategies I can use to help resolve this issue and obtain a solution?
Any insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

In version 14.1 your code run well and converges to some solution. This option should be removed MaxIterations -> 10000.

@AlexTrounev Thank you for your response! Could you please share the settings you used for the parameter θ? I am currently working with version 14.0 and would appreciate any additional details that might help with convergence.

In your code above \[Theta] = 0. Do you mean that we should make parametric research with $\theta$? Could you suggest what value $\theta$ we can use?

@AlexTrounev Yes, for example \[Theta] = Pi/3, or any value at range (0,Pi/2]

Is this boundary condition correct Cos[\[Theta]] d1y[1] + d1z[1] Sin[\[Theta]] == 0?

@AlexTrounev Yes, all these boundary conditions have been verified. However, if they turn out to result in the numerical difficulty, proper modifications can also be made.

Please, see my answer with solution for $\theta =\pi/3$.

Solution for $\theta=\pi/3$ can be computed in 3 step. On the first step we use the Euler wavelets collocation method and NMinimize to compute initial data for FindRoot as follows (please, note that we use algebraic equations for M1[s], M3[s] instead of differential equations for k1[s], k3[s])
eqs = {x'[s] == d3x[s], y'[s] == d3y[s], z'[s] == d3z[s], 
  n1'[s] == n2[s]*k3[s], n2'[s] == n3[s]*k1[s] - n1[s]*k3[s], 
  n3'[s] == -n2[s]*k1[s], d3x'[s] == -k1[s]*d2x[s], 
  d3y'[s] == -k1[s]*d2y[s], d3z'[s] == -k1[s]*d2z[s], 
  M1'[s] == M2[s]*k3[s] + n2[s], 
  M2'[s] == M3[s]*k1[s] - M1[s]*k3[s] - n1[s], M3'[s] == -M2[s]*k1[s],
   d1x'[s] == k3[s]*d2x[s], d2x'[s] == k1[s]*d3x[s] - k3[s]*d1x[s], 
  d1y'[s] == k3[s]*d2y[s], d2y'[s] == k1[s]*d3y[s] - k3[s]*d1y[s], 
  d1z'[s] == k3[s]*d2z[s], d2z'[s] == k1[s]*d3z[s] - k3[s]*d1z[s], 
  M1[s] == k1[s] (1 - k3[s]^4/k1[s]^4), 
  M3[s] == 2 (1 + k3[s]^2/k1[s]^2)*k3[s]}; bc0 = {x[0] == 0, 
  y[0] == 0, z[0] == 0, d1x[0] == 0, d1y[0] == 0, d1z[0] == 1, 
  d2x[0] == 0, d2y[0] == -1, d2z[0] == 0, d3x[0] == 1, d3y[0] == 0, 
  d3z[0] == 0};
bc1 = {x[1] == 0.5, y[1] == 0, z[1] == 0, 
  Cos[t] d1y[1] + d1z[1] Sin[t] == 0, d2x[1] == 0, 
  Cos[t] d3z[1] - d3y[1] Sin[t] == 0}; var = {x, y, z, d1x, d1y, d1z, 
  d2x, d2y, d2z, d3x, d3y, d3z, M1, M2, M3, n1, n2, n3, k1, 
  k3}; init = {9, 0, 0, 0, 0, -50, 9, 0}; ini = {M1[0] == init[[1]], 
  M2[0] == init[[2]], M3[0] == init[[3]], n1[0] == init[[4]], 
  n2[0] == init[[5]], n3[0] == init[[6]], k1[0] == init[[7]], 
  k3[0] == init[[8]]}; bc0add = {M1[0] == k1[0] (1 - k3[0]^4/k1[0]^4),
   M3[0] == 2 (1 + k3[0]^2/k1[0]^2)*k3[0]};

bc = Join[bc0, bc0add, bc1];

UE[m_, t_] := EulerE[m, t];
psi[k_, n_, m_, t_] := 
  Piecewise[{{2^(k/2) UE[m, 2^k t - 2 n + 1], (n - 1)/2^(k - 1) <= t <
       n/2^(k - 1)}, {0, True}}];
PsiE[k_, M_, t_] := 
 Flatten[Table[psi[k, n, m, t], {n, 1, 2^(k - 1)}, {m, 0, M - 1}]]
k0 = 2; M0 = 3; With[{k = k0, M = M0}, 
 nn = Length[Flatten[Table[1, {n, 1, 2^(k - 1)}, {m, 0, M - 1}]]]];
dx = 1/(nn); xl = Table[l*dx, {l, 0, nn}]; scol = 
 Table[(xl[[l - 1]] + xl[[l]])/2, {l, 2, nn + 1}]; Psijk = 
 With[{k = k0, M = M0}, PsiE[k, M, t1]]; Int1 = 
 With[{k = k0, M = M0}, Integrate[PsiE[k, M, t1], t1]];
Int2 = Integrate[Int1, t1];
Psi[y_] := Psijk /. t1 -> y; 
int1[y_] := Int1 /. t1 -> y; V = Array[vv, {nn, Length[var]}];


vart = Table[var[[i]]@s, {i, Length[var]}]; dvart = D[vart, s]; U = 
 Array[uu, {Length[var]}]; rule = 
 Flatten[Table[{vart[[i]] -> V[[All, i]] . int1[s] + U[[i]], 
    dvart[[i]] -> V[[All, i]] . Psi[s]}, {i, Length[var]}], 1];
eqn = (eqs[[All, 1]] - eqs[[All, 2]]) /. rule;
vart0 = vart /. s -> 0; vart1 = vart /. s -> 1; rulebc = 
 Flatten[Table[{vart0[[i]] -> V[[All, i]] . int1[0] + U[[i]], 
    vart1[[i]] -> V[[All, i]] . int1[1] + U[[i]]}, {i, Length[var]}], 
  1]; bcn = (bc[[All, 1]] - bc[[All, 2]]) /. rulebc;

eqAll = Join[Flatten@Table[eqn, {s, scol}], 
  bcn /. t -> Pi/3]; varAll = Join[Flatten@V, U];

em = Flatten@Table[eqn, {s, scol}]; bt = bcn /. t -> Pi/3;
sol1 = NMinimize[{em . em, Table[bt[[i]] == 0, {i, Length[bt]}]}, 
  varAll]; 

As results we have first initial state
Table[Plot[V[[All, i]] . int1[s] + U[[i]] /. sol1[[2]], {s, 0, 1}, 
  PlotLabel -> var[[i]]], {i, Length[var]}]


On the second step we polish initial solution sol1 with FindRoot as follows
sol = FindRoot[Table[eqAll[[i]] == 0, {i, Length[eqAll]}], 
  Table[{varAll[[i]], varAll[[i]] /. sol1[[2]]}, {i, Length[varAll]}],
   MaxIterations -> 1000];

As result we have initial data for NDSolve
inif = 
 Table[V[[All, i]] . int1[0] + U[[i]] /. sol, {i, Length[var]}]

Out[]= {0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., -1., 0., 1., 0., 0., 10.0989, \
-85.8467, 11.9765, -194.962, 28.5576, 455.311, -0.494493, 1.06396}

Finally, we use inif as initial data for NDSolve as
eqs0 = {x'[s] == d3x[s], y'[s] == d3y[s], z'[s] == d3z[s], 
   n1'[s] == n2[s]*k3[s], n2'[s] == n3[s]*k1[s] - n1[s]*k3[s], 
   n3'[s] == -n2[s]*k1[s], d3x'[s] == -k1[s]*d2x[s], 
   d3y'[s] == -k1[s]*d2y[s], d3z'[s] == -k1[s]*d2z[s], 
   M1'[s] == M2[s]*k3[s] + n2[s], 
   M2'[s] == M3[s]*k1[s] - M1[s]*k3[s] - n1[s], 
   M3'[s] == -M2[s]*k1[s], d1x'[s] == k3[s]*d2x[s], 
   d2x'[s] == k1[s]*d3x[s] - k3[s]*d1x[s], d1y'[s] == k3[s]*d2y[s], 
   d2y'[s] == k1[s]*d3y[s] - k3[s]*d1y[s], d1z'[s] == k3[s]*d2z[s], 
   d2z'[s] == k1[s]*d3z[s] - k3[s]*d1z[s], 
   k1'[s] == (k1[s]^4 (M2[s] k3[s] (k1[s]^2 + k3[s]^2) + 
         n2[s] (k1[s]^2 + 3 k3[s]^2)))/(((k1[s]^2 + k3[s]^2)^3)), 
   k3'[s] == (k1[s]^3 (4 n2[s] k3[s]^3 + 
         M2[s] (-k1[s]^4 + k3[s]^4)))/((2 (k1[s]^2 + k3[s]^2)^3))};

sol2 = NDSolve[{eqs0, bc} /. t -> Pi/3, var, {s, 0, 1}, 
  Method -> {"Shooting", 
    "StartingInitialConditions" -> Thread[vart0 == inif]}];

Visualization
Table[Plot[vart[[i]] /. sol2[[1]], {s, 0, 1}, 
  PlotLabel -> var[[i]]], {i, Length[var]}]



Thank you for your answer! I’m currently trying to understand the code you provided, and it has been very helpful. However, the results I get when running this code on my computer seem to be different from the ones you provided, and I’m still trying to understand why this might be the case. Also, since this is a boundary value problem (BVP), how can I obtain different solutions? I’d really appreciate your guidance. Thank you!

@Mikoto Please, note, that for $\theta =\pi/8, \pi/4$ solution converges on the second step but diverges with NDSolve.

@AlexTrounev Nice solution (+1).  Incidentally, I was able to find the θ=π/8,π/4 solutions with NDSolve.

@bbgodfrey Thank you very much for your answer!

This answer provides solutions over a wide range of θ for the system of equations given in the question.  Edited to extend range of θ to {0, 3/2 Pi}.
To begin, multiple solutions exist for θ = 0.  To illustrate, it is convenient to use the code in the question but with the first line, which defines θ and init, omitted and the last line replaced by
init = {9, 0, 0, 0, 0, -50, 9, 0};
sol = Flatten@NDSolve[{eqs, bc0, bc1, eqsadd, bc0add} /. θ -> 0, 
    var, {s, 0, 1}, Method -> {"Shooting", "StartingInitialConditions" -> 
    Thread[Through[var[[13 ;; 20]]@0] == init]}];
Chop[Through[var[[13 ;;]]@0] /. sol]
(* {1.20259, 0, 0, 0, -0.0000126724, 62.7307, 1.20259, 0} *)

which is, I presume, the same answer obtained by the OP.  In contrast, replacing this init by init = {9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 50, 9, 0}; yields
(* {3.5362, 0, 0, 0, 40.5173, 138.423, 3.5362, 0} *)

And, replacing it by init = {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 50, 1, 0}; yields
(* {1.20259, 0, 0, 0, -0.0000126724, 62.7307, 1.20259, 0} *)

Experimentation shows that the first two init arrays produce solutions only for θ slightly larger than zero, and for larger values NDSolve fails to converge.  (The question also makes this observation for the first init array.)  In contrast, the third init array yields solutions for θ as large as 1.2.  In particular,
init = {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 50, 1, 0};
sol = Flatten@NDSolve[{eqs, bc0, bc1, eqsadd, bc0add} /. θ -> Pi/3, 
    var, {s, 0, 1}, Method -> {"Shooting", "StartingInitialConditions" -> 
    Thread[Through[var[[13 ;; 20]]@0] == init]}];
Chop[Through[var[[13 ;;]]@0] /. sol]
(* {-0.895113, 2.19402, 6.87672, 8.13244, 4.69525, 60.9908, 1.31501, 1.49727} *)

produces the same answer obtained by Alex Trounev, including his second set of plots.  Solutions for θ -> Pi/4 and θ -> Pi/8 can be obtained in the same way:
{0.3292, 1.43142, 4.41963, 4.42162, 1.83149, 61.5116, 1.27868, 1.18698}

and
{1.09532, 0.544718, 1.75664, 1.25762, 0.25016, 62.3213, 1.21008, 0.67152}

Solutions over a range of θ can be obtained with
init = {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 50, 1, 0};
sol = Flatten@NDSolve[{eqs, bc0, bc1, eqsadd, bc0add} /. θ -> Pi/3, 
    var, {s, 0, 1}, Method -> {"Shooting", "StartingInitialConditions" -> 
    Thread[Through[var[[13 ;; 20]]@0] == init]}];
Chop[Through[var[[13 ;;]]@0] /. sol];

v0 = Transpose@Chop@FoldList[Flatten@NDSolveValue[{eqs, bc0, bc1, eqsadd, 
    bc0add} /. θ -> #2, Through[var[[13 ;;]]@0], {s, 0, 1}, 
    Method -> {"Shooting", "StartingInitialConditions" -> 
    Thread[Through[var[[13 ;; 20]]@0] == #1]}] &, %, Range[Pi/32, 3 Pi/2, Pi/32]];

Table[ListPlot[v0[[i]], DataRange -> {0, 3 Pi/2}, PlotRange -> All, 
    PlotLabel -> var[[12 + i]]@0, LabelStyle -> {Black, Bold, 10}], {i, 1, 8}];
GraphicsGrid[{%[[;; 3]], %[[4 ;; 6]], %[[7 ;;]]}, ImageSize -> Full]


Incidentally, I accidently found another solution for θ -> 15 Pi/32 with
(* {-1.32012, 46.399, -5.07669, 66.5504, 6.29148, 76.6438, 0.734378, -0.949765} *)

This suggests that there are multiple solutions for many values of θ.

Thank you! I think my question have been completely solved!

This is very nice solution (+1). I been able to compute solution for $\theta =\pi/3, \pi/4, \pi/8$, but not for so wide range.
